# Identifying first minutes of new month in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this which correctly pulls data for "last month"

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
WHERE CONCAT(MONTHNAME(t.create_date),' ', YEAR(t.create_date)) = CONCAT(MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),' ', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

I now want to extend this so that it also includes anything that happened in the first 2 minutes of the new/current month.  So I'm trying to do something like...

```
SELECT t.*
    FROM table t 
    WHERE (
CONCAT(MONTHNAME(t.create_date),' ', YEAR(t.create_date)) = CONCAT(MONTHNAME(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH),' ', YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
OR (t.create_date between STARTOFMONTH and (STARTOFMONTH + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
)
```

I've read a bunch of similar posts but can't find anything that seems to work for a general 'start of month + interval' approach (and I can't explicitly state the month in question since it obviously changes each month).  Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: You should provide the table structure and some example data.. And the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract 2 minutes.  I would suggest using `DATE_FORMAT()` for the comparison:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(t.create_date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m') OR
      DATE_FORMAT(t.create_date - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m);
```

You can simplify this to:

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE  - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m') IN
          (DATE_FORMAT(t.create_date, '%Y-%m'),
           DATE_FORMAT(t.create_date - INTERVAL 2 MINUTE, '%Y-%m')
          )
```

Comment: that works perfectly - especially like the simplification you added (you taught me something there!)  thanks (accepting in 3 mins)